# Entity Framework insert sublist into parent sublist

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I try to insert a list of `Answers` into `Questions` which in return it is inserted into `Exams`, all my code works just fine except one part, which is inserting new `Answers`.

Data is inserted just fine except Answers' data, whose data is not stored in the database, plus I try to get `QuestionId` so I can store it with Answer as a foreign key and I failed in that too.

API Controller

```
        public IActionResult addExam([FromBody] Exams exam)
        {
            try
            {
                if (exam == null)
                {
                    return StatusCode(401, "data is null");
                }

                var userId = this.help.GetCurrentUser(HttpContext);


                Exams exams = new Exams
                {
                    Name = exam.Name,
                    Number = exam.Number,
                    FullMarck = exam.FullMarck,
                    CreatedBy = userId,
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
                    Status = exam.Status
                };
               db.Exams.Add(exams);

                var questionsList = new List<Questions>();

                foreach (Questions item in exam.Questions)
                {
                    var question = new Questions
                    {

                        ExamId = exam.Id,
                        Points = item.Points,
                        CreatedBy = userId,
                        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
                        Status = item.Status,
                    };
                    questionsList.Add(question);

                }

               exams.Questions = questionsList;
                db.SaveChanges();
                foreach (Questions item in exam.Questions)
                {

                    var answersList = new List<Answers>();
                    foreach (Answers answers in item.Answers)

                        answersList.Add(new Answers
                        {
                            QuestionId = item.Id,
                            ExamAnswers = answers.ExamAnswers,
                            CreatedBy = userId,
                            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
                        });
                    item.Answers = answersList;

                }

                db.SaveChanges();
                return Ok("successfully created ");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, e.InnerException.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you tell us what happens that differs from your expectations ? Right now we don't know what "fine" means to you, and what "except" means in relation to this

Comment: Data is inserted just fine except Answers' data, whose data is not stored in database, plus I try to get Question ID so I can store it with Answer as a foreign key and I failed in that too.

Comment: ps; I personally would leverage the relevant option in EF/EFCore, to turn your entity names singular if your db tables use plural form

Comment: I appreciate your advice, although it wasn't me who created tables and chose their names.

Comment: I mean you should turn on the relevant portion to make it so the C# classes don't have plural names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you build your graph is a bit unusual. I would have expected it more like a single set of nested loops that takes your supplied model and populates entity collections without forced ids. EF will track the IDs; you don't need to worry about them; when you add a new Answer to a particular question.Answers collection, you don't need to tell the Answer what it's QuestionID is; EF knows based on which question it was added to. If the ID for a question is not yet set, because it is generated by the db and no save has occurred, then saving the question will generate an ID and EF will ripple the change out to all the owned Answers in the question.Answers; you don't need to micro manage it

Here's a pseudo code of how I would expect it to go:

```
//model is an ExamModel

Exam e = new Exam(); //exam is a db entity
e.Title = model.ExamTitle; //model is not a db entity

foreach(QuestionModel mq in model.Questions){ //enumerate all the questionmodel we got from the front end and build a db entity graph 

  Question q = new Question(); //make new db entity

  q.Subject = mq.QuestionHeader; //set entity property from model
  q.Body = mq.BodyText; //set property from model

  if(e.Questions == null) //not sure how your entities are declared, if this is already done elsewhere, remove it
    e.Questions = new List<Question>();

  e.Questions.Add(q); //add the question db entity to the exam db entity

  //notice I didn't set the question id. EF will do that- it knows what exam this question belongs to

  foreach(AnswerModel ma in mq.Answers){ //while our question db entity called q is still in scope let us add the related answers to it

    Answer a = new Answer(); //create EF entity
    a.Text = ma.AnswerText; //set db entity property from model property

    if(q.Answers == null)
      q.Answers = new List<Answer>();

    q.Answers.Add(a); //add the answer to the question db entity 
  }

}
//exam e now has a collection of questions that have each a collection of answers, save it to the db 
db.Exams.Add(e);
db.SaveChanges(); //only need one call to save changes on the whole graph
```

I think the way you've split your operations up hasn't created a connected graph of entities and/or the way you've forced the questionids of answers means EF hasn't kept the relationship to date upon saving.

You should also have a separation between the data objects arriving in your controller (I've called these ModelExam, ModelQuestion, ModelAnswer) and the entities in your EF (I've called these Exam, Question, Answer - yours are plural). This separation is achieved by having different classes for your front end controllers etc to use than your back end db context uses. At first it looks like things are being repeated for no good reason but eventually the system will become complex enough that not every db property can or should be exposed all the way to the front end and back, and the front end might need calculated or other non db based data. At this point you really need your front end data models to be completely separate things from your back end data entities

Comment: and I quote `The way you build your graph is a bit unusual. I would have expected it more like a single set of nested loops` I was so desperate that I had to try several routs and scenarios to make the code works as it was intended to be. \n and again I quote `without forced ids. EF will track the IDs; you don't need to worry about them` I didn't finish the rest of your answer, this line saved me a big time, it turned out you were right, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call db.SaveChanges() after adding new exam. In your case exam id is not auto generated and it is always 0 , so you cant save question with examid 0;

Comment: That part works as expected, no problems, however you're partially right, I tried to save question id as foreign ID in Question but I failed, even though I invoked  db.SaveChanges()  first.

Answer (score 0):

item.Answers = answersList; is false
exam.Questions.Answers  = answersList is true

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first `db.SaveChanges();` witch  is before last `foreach` loop. This will insert all your data at once and should do the job.